# Duplicate OneDrive Folders

Tags: onedrive, duplicate

I opended HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace and there are no multiple file names under Namespace.  I aslo seaarched for System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree but did not find a reference to any OneDrive.  One Onedrive folder is named users\paul\onedrive and the other is identified as Paul - Personal and the properties show it to be also located at C:\Users\Paul.  The data appears to be the same but the references show up in different place in File Manager,  How can I resolve for only one reference name?

Answer (score 0):

Download and then back up the One Drive data to a folder totally outside of One Drive.  Delete both One Drive instances.

Restart.

Restore the backup and all should be well.

Comment: Be sure the files are actually downloaded before you logout of OneDrive and delete the folder. Files not accessed regularly will have placeholder files.

Comment: Good point and I added the download step to my answer. I had assumed One Drive to be current.